# Retrieve full device twin data on device twin changed events

Tags: iot, onchange, azure-iot-hub

I would like to retrieve the full device twin data on the desired device twin or reported property changed. I was trying with below query filter but getting error.

An unknown error occurred while updating your IoT hub. Error Report: Invalid Routing Condition, RouteName:DeviceTwin-RptProp-Changed-dev, ErrorMessage:Message:Syntax error., Location :1:15, :1:22, Severity:Error . If you contact a support representative please include this correlation identifier: 3ef0e2ff-60c1-4133-af86-7e506af86faf, timestamp: 2021-11-29 04:24:01Z, errorcode: IH400104.

```sql
SELECT * FROM devices WHERE 
is_object($body.properties.desired)
```

Comment: Hi, could you add more details to your question? Are you retrieving this on the device, or on some other service? What have you tried to make this scenario work?

Comment: yes, I am retrieving from azure IoT device.    error: An unknown error occurred while updating your IoT hub. Error Report: Invalid Routing Condition, RouteName:DeviceTwin-RptProp-Changed-dev, ErrorMessage:Message:Syntax error., Location <start>:1:15, <end>:1:22, Severity:Error 
. If you contact a support representative please include this correlation identifier: 3ef0e2ff-60c1-4133-af86-7e506af86faf, timestamp: 2021-11-29 04:24:01Z, errorcode: IH400104.

Comment: Please update your question with these details. If you're running into an error, explain what steps you took that led to the error.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

To retrieve desired properties of your devices:

```
SELECT properties.desired
```

To retrieve reported properties of your devices:

```
SELECT properties.reported
```